# SQL Aggregation function to get concrete value

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, group-by, string-agg

I need help with an aggregation functionality.

what I want to know is if it is possible to extract a concrete value from a grouped query on one of the columns I return, like this

STORE

| fruit | color | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | red | 30 |
| apple | green | 5 |
| banana | yellow | 40 |
| berry | red | 5 |
| pear | green | 5 |

`SELECT SUM(stock), [?] FROM store GROUP BY fruit`

[?] -> i need to take a concrete value, for example RED. but the SUM must have 35 in apples.

can this be done without a subquery?

Thanks

I expect this results

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | red |

in this case the query does not make sense but for my personal case it does. I try to use STRING_AGG to take the data and make explode in my code, but its not the best way i think

Comment: Do you want one record only, or one record for each fruit?

Comment: Which value do you want to pick?

Comment: based on the desired result and table does `SELECT SUM(stock) 'Column A', color 'Column B' FROM store where color='red' GROUP BY color` works for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the GROUP BY clause. Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(stock), color
FROM store
GROUP BY color
```

This will return a list of all colors, and the sum of the stock for each color.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what you mean by a "concrete value" (singlular) as there are potentially two or more values... and you did mention STRING_AGG().  Also, you omitted the "fruit" from the query, which made things a bit confusing.  Nonetheless, this will get either one Color value or all color values using STRING_AGG() OR MAX() and without a sub-query:

```
-- the WITH is just a way to get your data into the query
    ;
WITH AdriansData AS
     (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('apple', 'red', 30),
                           ('apple', 'green', 5),
                           ('banana', 'yellow', 40),
                           ('berry', 'red',   5),
                           ('pear', 'green',    5)
                                           ) AS X (fruit, color, stock)
         )

         SELECT fruit,
                SUM(stock),
                STRING_AGG(color, ', ') AS Colors,
                MAX(color) AS JustOneColor
                FROM AdriansData

                GROUP BY fruit
```